# Access to instance property from another .js file

Tags: javascript

I'd like to show for example some stats in HTML subpage that are stored in Class object that is created while clicking on the button.

```
class Game {
    constructor(start) {
        this.stats = new Statistics();
        this.wallet = new Wallet(start);

        document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', this.startGame.bind(this));
}
```

And for example I want to see stats from stats variable on another subpage.
Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: If you included the classes in your html file in the right order you might just use the instance of Game like so : gameInstance.stats;

Comment: In that case I get error message in console: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null. I suppose because the instance is created while clicking on button on the main page.

Comment: In that case it might be a simple loading problem, do you have document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{ /* your code */}); around your code ?

Comment: Nope I dont. How can I use it to make it work properly?

Comment: it can be put around all your new (instanciations) so if you do them all in one place it will be easier

Answer (score 0):

Likely you want to store this in a global variable.

For example (not necessarily good practice):

`Game.js`

```
var currentGame = null; 

class Game {

    constructor() {
        currentGame = this;
        this.stats = new Statistics();
        // ....
    }
}
```

Now, you can just access your currentGame instance, which presumably there will be only one of. To get better knowledge on how to implement this pattern in a better way, research the **Singleton** pattern.

`console.log(currentGame.stats)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it still doesnt work in the way I want to. When I call a function currentGame.stats.showGameStats() on the main page it works properly. It is an array with three numbers, but when I call it on the subpage (where I want to show those values in table) I get an array with three zeros {0, 0, 0}